# How to get the sum of sales for each unique employee when doing an inner join on employee_id

Tags: mysql, select, sum, inner-join, distinct

I have done an inner join on two tables where they are joined on an "ID", and I am unsure how to get an output of the unique names with the sum of all of their sales.

```
SELECT staff.first_name, staff.last_name, payment.amount, staff.staff_id

FROM staff

INNER JOIN payment ON staff.staff_id = payment.staff_id;
```

**This is the output:**

[image: this is the output]

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Some people are beginners @strawberry

Comment: I don't get your point

Answer (score 1):

You could group by the name, and apply the aggregate `sum` function to the sales:

```
SELECT     staff.first_name, staff.last_name, SUM(payment.amount)
FROM       staff
INNER JOIN payment ON staff.staff_id = payment.staff_id
GROUP BY   staff.first_name, staff.last_name
```